# HTML | Значение submit как данные для формы

Tags: html, формы

В форме всего 1 кнопка отвечающая за своё значение.
Как сделать так что-бы кнопка имела это значение и при нажатии на неё форма её отправляла?

```html
<form method="get">
  <button type="submit" value="some info">some info
</form>
```

Comment: А сейчас разве не отправляет? Поидее должна произойти отправка методом GET по тому же самому адресу, что и адрес страницы

Comment: Ну для начала стоит этому значению задать какое-нибудь имя

Comment: @SwaD Не, не отправляет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы кнопка имела значение, а форма отправляла это значение при нажатии кнопки, вы можете добавить атрибут "name" к элементу кнопки и установить его значение в желаемое имя для данных формы. Например:

```
<form method="get">
  <button type="submit" name="button_value" value="some_info">some info</button>
</form>
```

Это создаст ввод формы с именем «button_value» и значением "some_info", когда кнопка будет нажата и отправлена.